# How to restore all default theme settings

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, ambiance

I have been having a problem for a while now, I was hoping that upgrading to 14.10 would solve it but it hasn't. My theme settings are messed up, presumably because I have installed other themes but there doesn't seem to be a way to re-set them to the original.

Icons appears to have boxes around them, this occurs on all themes even the default.

[image: System settings all icons have box around them]

Ironically things that should have boxes, don't - like tick boxes.

[image: Tick Boxes missing the box part]

This makes changing settings really difficult as it isn't clear where the tick box is, or even if it is there at all. Also some dialogue boxes are messed up too and don't look right:

[image: Dialogue box odd]

I say this happens on all themes, but there is one exception Adwaita displays everything OK (i.e. no borders around icons and proper tick boxes).

Things I have tried:

- Purging and re-installing light themes.
- Re-installing Adwaita theme
- Setting up a new user - problem remains there too.

I am not sure what else to do. Is there a way of restoring everything back to the defaults with themes? I assumed that re-installing the light themes and Adwaita would do that, but it hasn't. Is there some GTK file that can be restored, or something that can be re-installed?

Answer (score 1):

This problem got even worse with Nautilus crashing every time I tried to move a file, enter an address or open a file through another application. But I found the solution to this problem.

**libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0**

At some point I had installed a GNOME Testing PPA, I think a while back to try and resolve a problem I was having with Evolution, then forgot about it.

That PPA had updated my version of that file from Utopics stable version **libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:2.30.8-1** to the development version **libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:2.31.1-1**

I wasn’t able to downgrade that package but using the following command I was able to locate the troublesome PPA that had upgraded this package:

```
apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
```

This showed me the PPA that package belonged to. I then used PPA Purge to revert all the changes made by that particular PPA

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge [ppa to be purged]
```

This reverted all the changes and restored everything back to normal, everything from checkboxes to nautilus working.

I hope this helps someone else as this is a deeply frustrating problem, with no obvious answer or cause. I have said it before and I'll say it again, Ubuntu handles one of its best assets very poorly, PPAs. Not being able to quickly see your PPAs in a meaningful way (rather than a list of URLs) or see what packages they install, or indeed what PPA packages belong to is a serious flaw and leads to many hours of frustration. But with the Ubuntu Software Center being abandoned, PPAs are the only way to get up to date software.